# Camel CXFRS endpoint - auto wiring doesn't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, cxfrs

I'm trying to use Camel CXFRS component to expose Restful API. This is endpoint configuration:

```
cxfrs://http://0.0.0.0:8080/api?
    resourceClasses=com.myApp.UserResource
    &bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer
    &performInvocation=true
    &throwExceptionOnFailure=true
    &staticSubresourceResolution=true
```

in UserResource class:

```
@Component
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Path("/user")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public List<User> list() { return userService.list(); }
}
```

I have a problem with the code above:

userService is null, i.e. auto wiring does not work inside CXFRS resource class while working fine in other places.

Any suggestions are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: You can return json string instead of list

Comment: I updated the question, returning a list is not an issue :)